# how to get a specific row-column element from a string in python?

Tags: python

I want to get a specific row-column element from string.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['free','-m'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
out = out.decode("utf-8")
print(out)
```

Output is :

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3854        2778         299         351         776         407
Swap:          3909          80        3829
```

I want to get 3rd row, 3nd column element , that is 80.
How can i get that ?

Comment: split on lines then split lines, pick 3rd element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once decoded, split according to the lines, then pick the interesting line, split using `str.split` and pick the relevant field. Convert to integer:

```
output = """              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3854        2778         299         351         776         407
Swap:          3909          80        3829"""

print(int(output.splitlines()[2].split()[2]))
```

that gives `80` as expected